# Prove that $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0 \iff (z-z_0)^mf(z)$ is bounded but $(z-z_0)^{m-1}f(z)$ is not

Tags: complex-analysis

Where $f$ is analytic on some domain $D - \{z_0\}$. I'm struggling with the forward implication here.

Assume $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$. Then I can write $f$ as

$$f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^m} \text{ where }g(z_0) \ne 0$$

And

$$(z-z_0)^mf(z) = g(z)$$

$g(z)$ must also be analytic near $z_0$. So $(z-z_0)^mf(z)$ is bounded.

Now suppose that $(z-z_0)^{m-1}f(z)$ is bounded, then

$$(z-z_0)^{m-1}f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z-z_0} \text{ is bounded.}$$

Which means that $g(z)$ has a zero of order $1$ at $z_0$, which is a contradiction since $g(z_0) \ne 0$. So also $(z-z_0)^{m-1}f(z)$ is unbounded.

I'm slightly wary because the case involving $(z-z_0)^{m-1}f(z)$ being unbounded doesn't tie in with the first part of my proof. It seems to just be an "afterthought", or something which also happens to be true.

Comment: That's just like saying that $g(z_0)\ne 0$ is just an afterthought to the existence of analytic $g$. But without $g(z_0)\ne0$ you only state that $f$ has a pole of order *at least* $m$

Comment: Okay, after looking at your answer and the problem more I understand why the fact that $(z-z_0)^{m}$ is bounded but $(z-z_0)^{m-1}$ is important for the backward implication. However in the forward implication it is already given that $f$ has a pole of order exactly $m$. I think this was where my confusion came from; maybe I was too hasty to ask this question.

Comment: How is $g$ bounded if the domain is the entire plane??  Do you mean "locally bounded?"